# A better banner

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

While going around the site, our banner is the most prominent element on the page, and it does nothing to stop people from thinking this is about computer RPGs.

Should we add a "tabletop" writing over the title?

Comment: Only if we change it to read "Try talking to the problem player"

Answer (score 15):

No.

Why? Because this isn't a problem we have. We have what, one person every 2 or so months come and post a CRPG question? And usually they are pretty incoherent, and they've ignored all the new user information presented directly to them. More context clues would a) have a very low chance of helping and b) be addressing a corner use case that is better handled by clicking close once every two months. We have now officially spent more time discussing it than handling half a year worth of this particular use case.

Comment: I was more saddened because of that guy who said "but... this is a RPG site!".

Comment: Right, and there's nothing you can do about people who are just plain ignorant.  If they don't know a tabletop RPG exists, then saying "Tabletop RPG" won't shoo them off.  Using different graphics in our banner, similarly, doesn't stop that.

Answer (score 11):

While you *could* choose to see our top banner as "video gamish," and you might think that if you're unfamiliar with table top games, it's actually rather reminiscent of the types of art pieces you see in D&D, and other well illustrated RPG manuals.

Also, if you're paying any attention at all, you can see that the top banner includes *several* call outs to the fact that this is an RPG site.

- The site logo occupies a prominent place in the background of the header and is a d20.
- The edges of the banner fade to pencil drawings, not something a video game would have
- While not the top bar, the edge gutters of the site are filled with a grid that would be far more at home on a table than a computer monitor.

In other words, this site is pretty darn clear from it's design what it's missions is about. We're a table top RPG site.

And if it's not clear from the graphics, it's clear from the content. Questions about video games are shut down promptly and redirected to appropriate sites.

As [mxy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/140/mxyzplk) points out, confusion is pretty darn rare. We have a couple of questions every month, but they are quickly shuttered and sent on their way to a more appropriate sites (we even have custom close reasons for the two primary types of these).

So, overall, we've got a very nice design, with what are pretty clear call outs to our primary purpose (the fact that the art could be at home in a video game is mostly at testament to how much video games have borrowed from our hobby tbh). I see no need for a change.